# Is A Network Copy Timeout Likely To Show Up In Event Viewer Logs?

Tags: windows, networking, performance, network-share

I am trying to copy a 1.2Gb file between a Windows 7 workstation and a Windows Server 2003 system. That same server also hosts our enterprise's shares, most of them anyway.

The copy from the workstation to the server times out. If not in the event logs, where might this timeout event be recorded? Furthermore, what tools exist, other than doing something like running Wireshark, that would let me see the details of the failure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this sort of thing won't be in the event logs; however, if the root cause was something (like a NIC losing connection or failing hard drive) that would be recorded, you could see if there's anything correlated.

If the problem is being caused by the network, and if you have managed switches (assuming this is all on the same LAN), then you might see some errors on the port(s). That might be similar to what you could see in Wireshark from one host or the other, if you know how to read its output.

How are you doing the copy? Explorer drag-n-drop, or copy, xcopy, robocopy? I prefer to use the last one, because it has decent error codes, retry options, and logging. Try it with robocopy and see what results you get.

Comment: I am just dragging from a hard disk to a share. You've given me a bunch of info, though. I need to look at the logs from our managed switch. We've got the equipment; I just need to know how to get to it.

Comment: Never move big files, that you care about, on the network, from within the GUI. Always use a command-line tool. Start with that - if you have a repeatable problem, then start worrying about the cause.

Comment: Good to know. I'm used to the command line on Linux, but less so on Windows. I'll try ftp next time.

Comment: Um, dude, FTP isn't a native protocol on Windows unless you've installed IIS. Drag-and-drop, and all the other commands that I listed, use CIFS (SMB) which is the native way of moving files between Windows servers.

Answer (score 2):

Use Powershell for instead of a drag and drop. It's quite easy to log events with Powershell that your monitoring system can then pick up. And Copy-Item can use UNC paths.

```
$LOG=new-object System.Diagnostics.EventLog("Application")
$LOG.Source="Lawson Export Copy Script"

$EVENT=[System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType]::Information

$VAL="Copied virtual machine exports from $SOURCE to $DEST successfully."
$LOG.WriteEntry($VAL,$EVENT,0)
```